# Creating an alias in Knockout?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

At times I have elements from a view model that I am accessing multiple times in the view and I would like to be able to assign an alias from the view context to shorten things up.

I'm looking for something that would be similar to the `foreach` `as` alias or `with`, but that I am able to use on a single arbitrary access.

As an example, in the following I might want to alias `$root.form().budget.budgetEndDate` to `endDate`

```
<input id="foo" type="text" data-bind="dateTimePicker: $root.form().budget.budgetEndDate" />
```

Then I could rewrite the binding as

```
<input id="foo" type="text" data-bind="dateTimePicker: endDate" />
```

Comment: why don't you assign it to `self.endDate = ko.observable(self.form().budget.budgetEndDate)`;

Answer (score 0):

Two options.

First, for demo purposes only but not quite recommended, you ould pollute the global namespace:

```js
function Root() {
  this.form = ko.observable(new Form());
}

function Form() {
  this.budget = {
    budgetEndDate: ko.observable("dummy budget end date")
  };
  
  window["endDate"] = this.budget.budgetEndDate;
}

ko.applyBindings(new Root());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div>
  endDate outside form: <b data-bind="text: endDate"></b>
</div>
<div data-bind="with: form">
  <div>inside form: <b data-bind="text: endDate"></b></div>
  <div data-bind="with: budget">
    <div>inside form.budget: <b data-bind="text: endDate"></b></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Second, you could place it on `$root`:

```js
function Root() {
  this.form = ko.observable(new Form());
  
  this.endDate = this.form().budget.budgetEndDate;
}

function Form() {
  this.budget = {
    budgetEndDate: ko.observable("dummy budget end date")
  };
}

ko.applyBindings(new Root());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div>
  endDate outside form: <b data-bind="text: $root.endDate"></b>
</div>
<div data-bind="with: form">
  <div>inside form: <b data-bind="text: $root.endDate"></b></div>
  <div data-bind="with: budget">
    <div>inside form.budget: <b data-bind="text: $root.endDate"></b></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, on a subjective note, I'd consider this a design smell and/or an XY-problem. The place you bind to `budgetEndDate` should probably be the right context / view to access it directly. You should consider moving that observable to another part of your view model.